# How to use in-build Core Data XML serialisation?

Tags: core-data

I use Cocoa's Core Data framework which has the possibility of writing the data to XML via `NSXMLStoreType`.

For Copy & Paste in my app would I now like to write some core data objects to `NSPasteboard` and read it from there again. I thought that it should be able to read and write the in-build XML representation. Of course could I create a `Codable` interface for my core data classes, but I rather reuse the core data implementation.

How can I do this best?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this strategy is that the details of the XML store's schema implementation is internal to Apple. If you're going to use the results with another XML store, you should be ok. But I wouldn't expect the XML schema Apple uses to lend itself to being useful outside of that context, as it is written to disk, or depend on it not to change.

You can specify the store type when configuring an instance of `NSPersistantContainer` by setting its `persistentStoreDescriptions` property. `NSPersistentStoreDescription` has a type property, which can be set to `NSXMLStoreType`.

Comment: Thanks! I did indeed try this way, writing to temp file then reading the file. But this is way too complicated. It should be easier to access an XML version of my data.  But looking again very closely at documentation I don't see any more straightforward approach.

Comment: Have you looked at something like : https://github.com/ShawnMoore/XMLParsing or https://talk.objc.io/episodes/S01E115-building-a-custom-xml-decoder ?

Comment: Note: usually, it's a good idea to put multiple representations of an object on the pasteboard, such as a textual description, etc. You can also put a reference to the NSManagedObject as an instance of NSManagedObjectID with a private type. When your app receives the paste, use that private representation to fetch the original object from your persistent store, assuming it has been saved. That way, you don't need to serialize it. See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectid